# Finding difficulties in proving a theorem related to topology.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

**The theorem is** :

Let $A \subseteq X$, where $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. Then $x \in \bar A$ iff every open subset $U$ of $X$ containing $x$ intersects $A$, where $\bar A$ denotes closure of $A$.

**My attempt** :

First of all let us assume that $x \in \bar A$.Let $U$ be any open subset of $X$ containing $x$.We claim that $U \cap A \neq \phi$.If possible let $U \cap A = \phi$.Then $A \subseteq U^{c}$.Since $U$ is open, so $U^{c}$ is closed.Again since $\bar A$ is the smallest closed subset of $X$ containing $A$.Therefore we must have $\bar A \subseteq U^{c}$.Since $x \in \bar A$, so $x \in U^{c}$ $\implies x \notin U$, a contradiction to our hypothesis.Which proves our claim.

But I find difficulty in proving the converse part of the theorem.Please help me in proving the remaining part of the theorem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\notin \overline{A}$, then $x\in U:=X-\overline{A}$. But $U$ is open. By assumption $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$, a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by the sign $:=$?

Comment: Do you mean to say you take one such open set $U$ as $X \setminus \bar A$, since $ \bar A$ is closed and it's complement is open.

Comment: the symbol $:=$ means defintion, i.e. I am defining $U$ as $X-\overline{A}$. Also, $U$ is open since it is the complement of the closed set $\overline{A}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x$ is such that for every open subset $U$ of $X$  with $x \in U$ implies that $U \cap A \neq \varnothing$.

If $x$ is not in $cl_X(A)$ then $x \in ext(A)$. Then there exist a open set $V$ such that $x \in V \subseteq X \setminus A$, then $V \cap A = \varnothing$ which is a contradiction.